# How can I activate ipv6 on a router (from a mac)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ipv6

I have a wireless router. I went to http://test-ipv6.com/ and apparently the ipv6 is not activated. 
I also checked in my mac and in the system preferences (network) it appears that Configure IPv6: is set to Automatically but the Router, ipv6 address and length are empty.
(IPv4 of course is all set)

I have watched some videos on this but they all start using tools that they suppose are common knowledge and I don't have the slightless idea of what tools they are and they don't explain it, so I would appreciate a practical advice on this

Comment: What brand/model is your router ? Does your Internet Provider offer IPv6 ? If so, in what form ? Please EDIT that information into the question as it is very important for us to be able to answer. As it stands the question can't be answered. Too many unknowns.

Comment: First thing to check is that your ISP even supports it. Many don't yet.

Comment: So I guess the first thing is to call the ISP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could do it. 
First I called my provider and entered the homepage they set for each client. I found out that even though ipv6 was not used, it was provided by the provider. The problem was the router.

So I went to the homepage of the manufacturers of the router and I downloaded a program that permitted me to connect to the router.

Checking the manual and the program I could see that the default option was not to allow ipv6 so I checked it on. After that just in case (I don't know if it was necessary) I turn it off on,

And them ipv6 was on